# How to improve mongo aggregate query performance

Tags: database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, database-performance, sql-execution-plan

I am building an aggregation pipeline which has below stages

```
[
    { $match: {field1: "ABC"} },
    {
        $project: {

            date: true,
            state: true,
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                formattedDate: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } },
                status: "$Status"
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            date: "$_id.formattedDate",
            state: "$_id.state",
            _id: false,
            count: true
        }
    }
]
```

Please note, the query {field1: "XYZ"} is optional, So It could be there or not there for a given pipeline. So I added hint to my aggregate query to always use field1 as target index.

**Now to the actual problem:**
The collection has more than 1 million documents, and I have an index on field1. Below are the results I observed

**With query {field1: "XYZ"}**

```
nReturned: 12,
docsExamined: 12,
totalKeysExamined: 22,
totalDocsExamined: 12,
executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
executionTimeMillis: 1
```

**With query {field1: "ABC"}**

```
nReturned: 100023,
docsExamined: 100023,
totalKeysExamined: 100023,
totalDocsExamined: 100023,
executionTimeMillisEstimate: 9,
executionTimeMillis: 368
```

**Without query {}**

```
nReturned: 1378246,
docsExamined: 1378246,
totalKeysExamined: 1378246,
totalDocsExamined: 1378246,
executionTimeMillisEstimate: 313,
executionTimeMillis: 6350
```

In all three cases, Mongo is performing an IXSCAN, still, the last pipeline is taking around 7s. What can I do to improve the performance?

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: i'd faced similar problem so i can help you in this! try removing unnecessary stages like project it will definitely improve the performance.

Comment: The problem resides in `$group` stage, it's very slow. I recommend you store your `date` field without `HH:MM:SS` and try it again removing 2 stage. Also try `$graphLookup`, it may help you.

Comment: @harshitkohli, I will definitely try that out for small improvements, But the query still very slow even without that.

Comment: @Valijon I will try that.